# Pretty String Manipulation

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, vba, vb6

I have the following string which I wish to extract parts from:

```
<FONT COLOR="GREEN">201 KAR 2:340.</FONT>
```

In this particular case, I wish to extract the numbers 201,2, and 340, which I will later use to concatenate to form another string:

http://www.lrc.state.ky.us/kar/201/002/340reg.htm

I have a solution, but it is not easily readable, and it seems rather clunky.  It involves using the mid function.  Here it is:

```
intTitle = CInt(Mid(strFontTag, 
                    InStr(strFontTag, ">") + 1, 
                    (InStr(strFontTag, "KAR") - InStr(strFontTag, ">")) 
                           - 3))
```

I would like to know if perhaps there is a better way to approach this task.  I realize I could make some descriptive variable names, like intPosOfEndOfOpeningFontTag to describe what the first InStr function does, but it still feels clunky to me.

Should I be using some sort of split function, or regex, or some more elegant way that I have not come across yet?  I have been manipulating strings in this fashion for years, and I just feel there must be a better way.  Thanks.

Comment: Gotta appreciate someone who activly cares about readability... unforunatly I dont know vb.

Comment: How static is your input string. In otherwords, will you always have `<FONT COLOR="GREEN">{3 digits} KAR {1 digit}:{3 digits}.</FONT>` If you always have this exact format, a regex is about as simple as it comes. However, the more variation you can have in your input, the more complicated your regex can become.

Comment: Sorry, is this VB.net, VBA or VB6?

Comment: Looks more like *VBScript* with all of those Variant functions used in it.

Comment: To me your solution is just as readable as anything else being proposed below... Hide it away in a function and never look back.

Comment: Just add some comments explaining what the code does and why.

Answer (score 1):

regex pattern: `<FONT[^>]*>.*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?<\/FONT>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<FONT[^>]*>[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+):(\d+)[^\d]*</FONT>
```

Comment: Some people don't know what regular expressions are!

Answer (score 1):

**The class**

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Linq

Public Class clsTester
    'methods
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetTitleUsingRegEx(ByVal fpath$) As XElement
        'use this function if your input string is not a well-formed
        Dim result As New XElement(<result/>)
        Try
            Dim q = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(fpath), Me.titPattern1, RegexOptions.None)
            For Each mt As Match In q
                Dim t As New XElement(<title/>)
                t.Add(New XAttribute("name", mt.Groups("name").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num1", mt.Groups("id_1").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num2", mt.Groups("id_2").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num3", mt.Groups("id_3").Value))
                t.Add(mt.Value)
                result.Add(t)
            Next mt
            Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            result.Add(<error><%= ex.ToString %></error>)
            Return result
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function GetTitleUsingXDocument(ByVal fpath$) As XElement
        'use this function if your input string is well-formed
        Dim result As New XElement(<result/>)
        Try
            Dim q = XElement.Load(fpath).Descendants().Where(Function(c) Regex.IsMatch(c.Name.LocalName, "(?is)^font$")).Where(Function(c) Regex.IsMatch(c.Value, Me.titPattern2, RegexOptions.None))
            For Each nd As XElement In q
                Dim s = Regex.Match(nd.Value, Me.titPattern2, RegexOptions.None)
                Dim t As New XElement(<title/>)
                t.Add(New XAttribute("name", s.Groups("name").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num1", s.Groups("id_1").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num2", s.Groups("id_2").Value))
                t.Add(New XAttribute("num3", s.Groups("id_3").Value))
                t.Add(nd.Value)
                result.Add(t)

            Next nd
            Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            result.Add(<error><%= ex.ToString %></error>)
            Return result
        End Try
    End Function

    'fields
    Private titPattern1$ = "(?is)(?<=<font[^<>]*>)(?<id_1>\d+)\s+(?<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?<id_2>\d+):(?<id_3>\d+)(?=\.?</font>)"
    Private titPattern2$ = "(?is)^(?<id_1>\d+)\s+(?<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?<id_2>\d+):(?<id_3>\d+)\.?$"
End Class
```

**The usage**

```
Sub Main()
        Dim y = New clsTester().GetTitleUsingRegEx("C:\test.htm")
        If y.<error>.Count = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result from GetTitleUsingRegEx:{0}{1}", vbCrLf, y.ToString))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(y...<error>.First().Value)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("")
        Dim z = New clsTester().GetTitleUsingXDocument("C:\test.htm")

        If z.<error>.Count = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result from GetTitleUsingXDocument:{0}{1}", vbCrLf, z.ToString))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(z...<error>.First().Value)
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

---

***Hope this helps.***

Comment: Can you maybe explain or at least comment your code? It seems to do vastly more than was actually asked for with no obvious "the result is XYZ".

Comment: @Deanna: have you tiried the code? While posting answer in short period of time it is not always possible to comment every piece of code with details. It also requies that the asker should have knowledge of that.

Comment: That's no reason not to explain 2 pages of uncommented black box (and seemingly overkill) code for a simple string extraction. You've had 4 months since to comment it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jean-François Corbett has it right.

Hide it away in a function and never look back

Change your code to this:

```
intTitle = GetCodesFromColorTag("<FONT COLOR="GREEN">201 KAR 2:340.</FONT>")
```

Create a new function:

```
Public Function GetCodesFromColorTag(FontTag as String) as Integer

    Return CInt(Mid(FontTag, InStr(FontTag, ">") + 1, 
                (InStr(FontTag, "KAR") - InStr(FontTag, ">")) 
                - 3))

End Function
```